# Fullcalendar Scheduler: Separate biz hours per resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am wondering if anyone has been able to manipulate the rendering of cells to display a business hours type effect?

I can globally set business hours in fullcalendar which trickles down to the scheduler plugin. However the goal here is to define separate 'availability' for a given resource.

I haven't got any code to show at the moment as I have just started to look into this problem and don't know if it is even possible.

Any advice would be greatfully recieved.

Cheers

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: Hey. Yeah, kind of. I ended up using the built in functionality: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ note the 'rendering' section. You can add events in the background: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ha, that's exactly the path I have taken, cheers anyway :)